# prove that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, set-partition

QUESTION: Let $S$ be a subset of $G$ such that the identity element $1 \in S$. Assume that the subsets $aS := \{as \mid s \in
S\} \subseteq G$ for $a \in G$ form a partition of $G$. Prove that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.

[image: my work]

This is my solution thus far. Can someone check if it is remotely correct and where I can improve?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: For a start, you need to make it clear that $S$ is nonempty. This is given, true, but it is like the subset property.

Comment: @Shaun it's already given $1\in S $.

Comment: The given proof looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation involving $\{1\}$ is unnecessary and seems wrong. (Did you mean $\{x\}\cup\dots$ instead of $\{1\}\cup\dots$ ?) For that step, I'd just write "we have $x=x1\in xS$". Also, you might want to note that $S=1S$ is of the form $aS$ in order to apply the fact about the partition. Besides that, LGTM.

Comment: I think $1$ is here as a representator of identity.

Comment: yes 1 is the representer of the identity